# cached malloc performance improvements

Tags: c, performance, caching

If my application dynamically allocates and frees memory numerous times, each time for objects of the same size; is it meaningful to wrap the malloc and the free with a cache of allocated memory for improving the performance? or do implementations of mallocs already do this?

Comment: You're talking about a *memory pool*.  `malloc` will already implement one under the hood.  It's possible to write your own that does a better job for specific use-cases, but unless you know what you're doing, you're better off relying on the default.  Have you profiled your code to identify this as a problem?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Not yet, I have some problems in accessing the cluster that i'm using and i have to wait o do that. BTW I'm trying first to figure out what is the problem. I allocate millions of descriptors that have an average time life of 2.5 us . But on average keeping a pool of 10000 should work. I was thinking if its worth to implement it of is useless because was already implemented.

Comment: It's often a good idea to avoid memory allocations wherever you can before you start horsing around with how memory gets allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The the [boost::pool](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/pool/doc/html/) class that can do it for you.

Another faster and easier way is to use an alternative malloc library from [TBB](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/) (tbbmalloc) or [Google malloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) (tcmalloc). Both are much faster than the default malloc and only require linking with a library so n code change is required.

I used tbbmalloc and gained a massive 2x boost on several applications.